# Fizz Buzz Solution: Unexpected Token Function?

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I'm having some frustration with this code. I may not be seeing it.
I keep getting either an "Unexpected Token" or "ILLEGAL" error (the latter which completely preplexed me, considering I've never seen an error like that before in  my life.

I've been double checking the syntax and I'm thinking it may be something I'm just not catching?

```js
function fizzBuzz(n) {
2    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++) {
3    if (n%3===0) {
4    print ("fizz")
5    }
6    if (n%5===0) {
7    print ("buzz")
8    }
9    if (i%3 !== 0 && i%5 !== 0) {
10      return [i];
11    }
12    }
13    }
14    
15    
16    fizzBuzz(100);
```

I'd be thankful for the help! <3

Comment: After code formatting ... maybe use console.log instead of print

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes:

- remove line numbers,
- check first for `'fizz buzz'` value and use `console.log` for output. Then use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement for jumping to top for next loop,
- use `i` instead of `n` for checking.

```js
function fizzBuzz(n) {
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            console.log("fizz buzz");
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            console.log("fizz");
            continue;
        }
        if (i % 5 === 0) {
            console.log("buzz");
            continue;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}

fizzBuzz(100);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you Nina! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

```
function fizzBuzz(n) {
2    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++) {
3    if (n%3===0) {                You're checking if the maximum number (n) is divisible by 3.
4    print ("fizz")                You should be checking i.
5    }
6    if (n%5===0) {                You're checking if the maximum number (n) is divisible by 5.
7    print ("buzz")                You should be checking i.
8    }
9    if (i%3 !== 0 && i%5 !== 0) {
10      return [i];                You're returning an array with a single element: i.
11    }                            You should print i instead.
12    }
13    }
14    
15    
16    fizzBuzz(100);
```

The line numbers are what's causing the "ILLEGAL" error. Remove them.

`print` in JavaScript opens the print dialog to literally print paper out of a printer. Use `console.log`

If a number is divisible by both 3 and 5, `fizzbuzz` should be printed. Your code prints `fizz` and `buzz` on separate lines.

**Working version ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPZ0pIK_wsc ) :**

```js
function fizzBuzz(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        var printVal = "";
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            printVal += "fizz";
        }
        if (i % 5 === 0) {
            printVal += "buzz";
        }
        if (printVal === "") {
            printVal = i;
        }
        console.log(printVal);
    }
}
       
fizzBuzz(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets decrease number of if statements, I have seen many fizzbuzzs - I would like to try another approach

```js
const fizzBuzz = (i = 0, ret) => {
  while (++i, ret = '', i <= 100) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      ret += `fizz`
    }
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      ret += `buzz`
    }
    console.log(ret || i)
  }
}

fizzBuzz()
```

The most important part is `console.log(ret || i)` - empty string is **falsy value**, so console will log `ret` if there is some value **or** current `i` value

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to print to your browser's console, use `console.log()` instead of `print()`, since `print()` will open the printer preview in a browser. I'm using Chrome. Remember to check the console by pressing F12 and clicking on "console" in case you've created a html file that includes your javascript script.

Since you are iterating i until it reaches the value of n, you if statements should look like:

`if(i%3===0){
 // your code... 
   }`

Based on your code, it seems like you want to check for a value that is not a multiple of 3 && a multiple of 5. However, the fizzbuzz challenge requires to print fizzbuzz when encountering a number that is both a multiple of 3 && a multiple of 5. So, you'll need to add the following condition:

```
       if (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) {
            console.log("fizzbuzz");
            continue; /* Continue may or may not be necessary depending on your program's logic. Continue allows to re-enter the loop 
without checking for the remaining if statements. If you use continue, this condition must be the first if statement inside the loop */
            }
```

Your function doesn't need to return anything, since you're using console.log() to visualize the values in each loop iteration. That's why you need to change `return [i]` for `console.log(i)`.

Don't give up and keep trying!

If you have further questions, I'll be glad to help you.